# loop through datatable from webmethod in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, loops, datatable

i there is any way to loop through columns of DataTable that Returned  from web method in javascript
 THE WebMethod is like this

```
[WebMethod]
public  static  DataTable  GetDataTable()
{
   // connecting Database and execute Query that retrieving Data Into 
   //TargetTable
    return TargetTable;
}
```

i need to loop through TargetTable Rows,columns
i have used
`var tblData = PageMethods.GetDataTable();`
but it return undefined ;

Comment: Don't return a DataTable from a web method. Convert it to strongly typed model objects.

Comment: how can i do this ,i haven't idea how to implement

Comment: You don't know how to query data from a database and store it in a class? I suggest you take a look at a micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).